# Customtabs javascript method

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

Is there is a way to run javascript method on custom tabs or external web browser, not a webview.

```
CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder().build();           
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context,Uri.parse(url));
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution for this ?